# Advantage in considering an almost complex structure

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, complex-geometry, almost-complex

Let $M$ be a real Riemannian manifold of even dimension, what are the advantages of considering an almost complex structure on it rather than only real?

Comment: Complex structures are insanely powerful, and almost complex structures give you much of that power? This is like asking what the advantages are for using harmonic functions over real analytic functions. Are you just looking for a list of properties? I would recommend reading a bit online about complex structures and then see what carries over with almost complex structures

Comment: From what perspective are you approaching this? I am wary of merely listing a bunch of properties that might be meaningless to you if you haven't encountered contexts we would desire them

Comment: @Brevan Ellefsen - thank you for your answer, yes I'm interested in a list of properties that offers an almost complex structure to a real manifold.

Comment: @Brevan Ellefsen - from the prospective of the Riemannian (real) warped product manifold with almost Hermitian structure

Comment: @Brevarian Ellefsen - Or for example if I consider $M=N \times_f F$ where $M, N$ and $F$ are real but $N$ admit also an almost complex structure, what are the properties that $M$ acquires rather than $N$ has only real structure?

Comment: I must admit I am unsure in the product case, since I don't believe $M$ will have very many of the properties that make an almost complex manifold nice. I'm afraid you might have to wait for someone more knowledge on that to answer

Comment: ok, Thank you very much anyway